# How to eliminate vertical space between two components?

Tags: vaadin

I have two components intended to be a label underlined with a embedded red line:-

```
    Embedded line= new Embedded("", new ThemeResource(RED_LINE));

    LabelExt lblLoadFile = new LabelExt(this.app.res_grid_lables.LOAD_FILE);

    this.addComponent(lblLoadFile);
    this.addComponent(line);
```

But there seems to be a space between these two (of about 20 px). How to eliminate it so that the embedded resource looks like an underline?

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS to do this instead.

Create CSS like this

```
   .red-underline{   
   border-bottom: red solid 2px;  
   }
```

Then your code would need to look like this

```
   LabelExt lblLoadFile = new LabelExt(this.app.res_grid_lables.LOAD_FILE);
   lblLoadFile.addStyleName("red-underline");
   this.addComponent(lblLoadFile);
```

You will need to find somewhere to add the CSS. Personally I use the @StyleSheet annotation to bring a css file in from within the java project.